# Regex match whole string

Tags: c++, regex, string

I have the following pattern:

> ```
> [ \n\t]*([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)[ \n\t]+((char)[ \n\t]*\[[ \n\t]*([0-9]+)[ \t\n]*\]|(char)|(int)|(double)|(bool)|(blob)[ \n\t]*\[[ \n\t]*([0-9]+)[ \t\n]*\])[ \n\t]*
> ```

You can try it here: http://regex101.com/r/vA0xG9

In the first capturing group `([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)`, I want to grab words that only starts with `a-zA-Z`.

The two following strings matches equally:

> ```
> cpf char[12]
> ```

,

> ```
> 9cpf char[12]
> ```

It ignores the `9` digit and matches equally to the first string.

I've tried to use this capturing group: `(ˆ[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$)`, but it didn't work.

I'm using lib `regex.h`.

What should I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put ^ at the beginning of the whole thing and $ at the end

```
^[ \n\t]*([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)[ \n\t]+((char)[ \n\t]*\[[ \n\t]*([0-9]+)[ \t\n]*\]|(char)|(int)|(double)|(bool)|(blob)[ \n\t]*\[[ \n\t]*([0-9]+)[ \t\n]*\])[ \n\t]*$
```

I would also suggest \s instead of [ \n\t] if you want to match whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, there is a handy regex method that anchors the match to the whole string automatically: [`std::regex_match`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match):

> Determines if the regular expression e matches the entire target character sequence, which may be specified as [std::string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), a C-string, or an iterator pair.

This way, you will avoid issues with mistyped `^` as `ˆ` as well as cases when you have alternation (e.g. `^A|B$` won't match strings only equal to `A` or `B`, you need `^(A|B)$` or `^(?:A|B)$`).

Note that there is an equivalent [`boost::regex_match`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_match.html) method.