# How to remove the first character if it's a comma using QRegExp?

Tags: qt, qregexp, qregularexpression

I have the following QRegExpValidator

```
QRegExpValidator doubleValidator = new QRegExpValidator(QRegExp("[-+]?[0-9]*[\\.,]?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?"));
```

It's supposed to be a Double numbers validator that accepts numbers, only one "e" sign, one comma OR dot and one + or - sign at the beggining of the string or after the "e" sign. It works for every case, except that it allows the string to start with a comma or dot. I tried to use **[^\\.,]** and variations and they did in fact work, but in this case, it would also allow to put two +- signs.

How can I make this to work?

Comment: A duplicate of [Regex match whole string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22432558/regex-match-whole-string)

Comment: Use `"^[-+]?[0-9]*[\\.,]?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$"`

Comment: It still allowing to input a dot or comma at the beggining

Comment: Yes, because you have `[0-9]*` there. What are the allowed types of numbers? If you do not allow `.0` like number use `"^[-+]?[0-9]+([.,][0-9]+)?([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[-+]?[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?` pattern allows the `,` or `.` at the start because `[-+]?` and `[0-9]*` can match empty strings due to the `?` (one or zero occurrences) and `*` (zero or more occurrences)  quantifiers, and then `[.,]` matches a single occurrence of `.` or `,`. Besides, if the method you are using does not anchor the pattern by default, you also need `^` and `$` anchors around the pattern.

I suggest fixing that with

```
"^[-+]?[0-9]+([.,][0-9]+)?([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$"
 ^          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                  ^
```

Note you do not need to escape the dot inside a character class, `[.]` always matches a dot char only.

The `[0-9]+([.,][0-9]+)?` matches 1+ digits and then an optional sequence of a `.` or `,` followed with 1+ digits.

Comment: I'm using Qt; it always assumes the "^E$" on QRegExpValidator; I forgot to include that hehe. Thanks, buddy